# What is the first semicolon in `addCommandAlias` method used for in SBT?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

For example, I have to write an alias like this:

```
addCommandAlias("make-idea", ";updateClassifiers; updateSbtClassifiers; gen-idea sbt-classifiers")
```

Instead of

```
addCommandAlias("make-idea", "updateClassifiers; updateSbtClassifiers; gen-idea sbt-classifiers")
```

If I skip the first semicolon, sbt will complain.. Does anyone have ideas about what does the first `;` in the second argument of `addCommandAlias` do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just sbt's syntax to specify multiple commands. This is normal sbt CLI behavior and is not specific to `addCommandAlias`.

The same happens in the sbt shell:

```
sbt> updateClassifiers; updateSbtClassifiers; gen-idea sbt-classifiers
[error] Expected ID character
// etc.

sbt> ; updateClassifiers; updateSbtClassifiers; gen-idea sbt-classifiers
// as expected
```